WebSocket closing connection after 60 seconds
I have a websocket connection for my python service running on EKS, for which I have an LB infront of.
When running the service locally, any request succeeds through the websocket. However, as soon as I deploy this all requests that take longer than 60 seconds fail. This indicates that some infra setting is getting in the way.
I have updated my helm chart to include this annotation:
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds=600

I can see this reflected in AWS as the LB now has an increased timeout of 600 seconds, but I am still facing the same issue of timing out after 60 seconds.
We are not using nginx.
